# How to union data of multiple fields

Tags: sql-server

I am using Sql Server. I am trying to use a union to make sure that I get all driver phones and other values from a transactions table based on an Establishment Code, and union them with same DriverPhone and other values from a connection table based on the same Establishment code. The connection table query (second half of union) retrieves one more field val (ETA) than it retrieves from the transactions table. Some driver phones might be on one table and not the other, or vice versa, or be on both. **So I need a list of all drivers, between the two tables, with no duplicate drivers, but I want them sorted by the ETA value from the connections table.** Is it possible to do this? I don't think what I have will work, and I think it will only sort the connection part of the query by ETA, when I need the unioned result set itself to be sorted by ETA and if anybody can point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
SqlCommand getDrivers = new SqlCommand("SELECT DriverPhone, UserHandle FROM Transactions WHERE EstablishmentCode = @ec UNION SELECT PhoneNumber, UserHandle, ETA FROM Connection WHERE EstablishmentCode = @ec AND Dispatcher = @disp OrderBy ETA", myTransactions);
getDrivers.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ec", "ec");
getDrivers.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disp", false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ETA` into your first query so that both queries in your UNION query have the same number of fields. Since you don't have an `ETA` field in your `Transactions` table, just set that field to NULL:

```
SqlCommand getDrivers = new SqlCommand("SELECT DriverPhone, UserHandle, CAST(NULL AS DATE) as ETA FROM Transactions WHERE EstablishmentCode = @ec UNION SELECT PhoneNumber, UserHandle, ETA FROM Connection WHERE EstablishmentCode = @ec AND Dispatcher = @disp OrderBy ETA", myTransactions);
getDrivers.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ec", "ec");
getDrivers.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disp", false);
```

Comment: Hi jNevill, thanks for the answer. A clarification.ETA is a string value in the connection table, There is also a string column called ETA in the transactions table, but that represents a transaction eta, not a driver's total eta, whereas the connection table holds the total driver eta, based on total of etas for his entries in transactions table. And I also don't understand casting the null as a date. thx.

Comment: I casted the NULL as date under the assumption that the ETA value in your `connection` table. If that is a string, then cast the NULL as varchar. The UNION has to have the same number of fields, and must also have the same field types.